# Trigger hover drop down menu onload

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I'd like to make a hover drop down menu appear down already as the page loads. I'm currently using CSS and HTML to make the menu drop down on hover, but would like the menu to appear when a page from within that drop down is loaded, but then will disappear when the mouse hovers over a different drop down.

Here's my HTML at the moment:

```
            <ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    <ul>
    </br>
        <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Info</a>
    <ul>
    </br>
        <li><a href="#">Info 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
#nav, #nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
text-align:left;
}

#nav a {
display: block;
text-align:left;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
padding-right:3.5px;
text-align:left;
}

#nav li ul {
position: absolute;
width: 10em;
visibility: hidden;
text-align:left;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
text-align:left;
```

At the moment, the drop down works perfectly, but I would like the 'Projects' drop down to appear down when a 'Project' page is loaded, but for this to disappear when the mouse hovers over 'Info', and the same to happen to the 'Info' drop down when an 'Info' page is loaded. Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: You need some jQuery here to add a class to the drop down you want to be visible.

Comment: You can use CSS to this.

Answer (score 0):

@otinanai is right

Here's the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHe4K/

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="hovered"><a href="#">Projects</a>
...
```

CSS:

```
#nav li ul {
position: absolute;
width: 10em;
visibility: hidden;
text-align:left;
}

#nav li.hovered ul{
visibility: visible;
text-align:left;
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#nav li').each(function() {
        $(this).on('mouseenter', function(){
            $(this).addClass('hovered');    
        });
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hovered');    
        });    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav li.current ul {
   visibility: visible;
}

#nav:hover li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

this works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/k9bTE/